# How to make a button with added functionality with @media query

Tags: css, angular

I would like my button to dim the background onclick when the screen is mobile size. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply change the style class as below and make sure the style class is inside the media query

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-ishizaka-stej8?file=/src/app/app.component.css:251-344)
try it with different screen sizes.

component.ts

```
  clicked: boolean = false;

  handleClick(event?: MouseEvent) {
    if (event) { event.stopPropagation(); }
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
  }
```

template.html

```
<div>
  <button
    class="btn"
    [ngClass]="{'change-color': clicked}"
    (click)="handleClick()"
  >
    Click me!
  </button>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
.btn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.change-color {
  background-color: #f7e226;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .change-color {
    background-color: #4caf50;
  }
}
```